# How are random numbers generated in R when random seed is fixed?

Tags: r, random

I am running some stochastic simulation experiments and in one step I want to estimate the correlation between random numbers when the underlying source of randomness is the same, i.e., common U(0,1) random numbers.

I thought the following two code segments should produce the same result.

```
set.seed(1000)
a_1 = rgamma(100, 3, 4)
set.seed(1000)
b_1 = rgamma(100, 4, 5)
cor(a_1,b_1)

set.seed(1000)
u = runif(100)
a_2 = qgamma(u, 3, 4)
b_2 = qgamma(u, 4, 5)
cor(a_2,b_2)
```

But the results are different

```
> cor(a_1,b_1)
[1] -0.04139218
> cor(a_2,b_2)
[1] 0.9993478
```

Which a fixed random seed, I expect the correlations to be close to 1 (as it is the case in the second code segment). However, the outputs in the first code segment is surprising

1. For this specific seed (1000), the correlation in the first segment has a negative sign and a very small magnitude. Neither the sign nor the magnitude makes sense...
2. When playing around with different seeds (e.g., 1, 10, 100, 1000), the correlation in the first segment changes significantly while the correlation in the second segment is quite stable.

Can anyone give some insights about how R samples random numbers from the same seed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think those should give the same result?

Comment: I agree, I don't see why those should be equal at all. Those two sets of statements are not doing the same thing. Not all sampling in R starts with the uniform distribution.

Comment: I haven't looked too much into the sampler but this question did bring something up that I didn't notice before.  If you take that first chunk of code and plot(a_1, b_1) you do get a straight line with one deviant (R 3.3.1 windows 7).  Increasing the seed to 10, 100, 1000 adds more variation but we can still detect a pattern along the y=x diagonal.  Interesting. Using the same seed one shouldn't expect the same degree of what I'll call pseudo-independence as you get otherwise but it's something to keep in mind for simulations.t

Comment: @Dason The two segments should be the same if sampling starts with the uniform distribution (so the difference suggests that this is not the case, at least not for gamma distribution). So my question is HOW the random numbers are sampled. Specifically, what should we expect the common random seed affect the correlation if it weren't propagated through the uniform random variable then through inverse CDF.

Comment: @MrFlick Even though the sampling in R may not start with uniform distribution, the common random seed should introduce some dependence (and hence some correlation). When I run the first code segment with seed 1000 (thanks Dason for the suggestion), the correlation is -0.041 (R 3.4.0 Window 10). Neither the magnitude nor the sign makes sense...I just wonder how R samples random numbers with the same seed...

Comment: Have you already read the help file for `Random` in R? It might contain some information about your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(1)
u = runif(1000)
```

Seems to be a typo for

```
set.seed(1000)
u = runif(100)
```

If so, the only reason that I see for you thinking that the two experiments should be equivalent is that you are hypothesizing that `rgamma(100, 3, 4)` is generated by [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling): start with `runif(100)` and then run those 100 numbers through the inverse of the cdf for a gamma random variable with parameters 3 and 4. However, the Wikipedia article on gamma random variables suggest that [more sophisticated methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Generating_gamma-distributed_random_variables) are used in generating gamma random variables (methods which involve multiple calls to the underlying PRNG).

`?rgamma` shows that R uses the Ahrens-Dieter algorithm that the Wikipedia article discusses. Thus there is no reason to expect that your two computations will yield the same result.

If what I took to be a typo at the beginning of my answer is what you actually intended then I have absolutely no idea why you would think that they should be equivalent, since they would then lack the "same seed" that you mention and furthermore correspond to different sample sizes.

Comment: You are right about the typo (many thanks, I edited the question to avoid confusions).

Comment: As a follow-up question: When doing Monte Carlo simulation, we tend to think that fixing the random seed (rather than storing common random numbers) could create correlation in simulation outputs,  which may be helpful in some applications (for example, control variate). But the example given in the question seems to suggest fixing the seed isn't very helpful in creating the correlation. Any comment?